# How to get the table name in trigger on which ddl operation will be performed

Tags: oracle, security, plsql

I want to do something like

```
create or replace trigger t1 before ddl on database
begin
insert into table1 values(//the table name on which the ddl will be performed);
end;
```

so if i create a table named "Hello" than "Hello"(table name) will be inserted in table1

so i don't know how to fetch the table name actually

Answer (score 5):

[That's show here in the Database Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-266DBF6D-AA74-490C-ADE5-962C10708C2D)

So you could do something like...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ddl_trig
AFTER DDL
ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO loguser.ddl_log
  (user_name, ddl_date, ddl_type,
   object_type, owner,
   object_name)
  VALUES
  (ora_login_user, SYSDATE, ora_sysevent,
   ora_dict_obj_type, ora_dict_obj_owner,
   ora_dict_obj_name);
END ddl_trig;
/
```

BUT, you shouldn't build your own auditing software/code. You should instead use the database's built in auditing system.

[See this.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html#GUID-94381464-53A3-421B-8F13-BD171C867405)

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am a product manager on the database team.*